# Re-creating a Visual Basic Program in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, excel

I have created a program in Visual Studio 2013 using Visual Basic.  This program allows the user to enter in certain criteria via controls then they click on a button and the program searches an excel document with several spreadsheets and returns the appropriate information to the user.  The program runs perfectly as it was intended (thought a little slower than I would like).  I have now been charged with making this program a web application.

I have done enough research and have settled on using ASP.NET and visual basic (If there are other suggestions I would welcome them).  I have re-created the GUI in ASP.NET as best as I could and I'm now left with the extensive coding part.  My first question is by turning this program into a web app can I still use Excel?  How would that work on the server side instead of everything being on the client side.  Is there a completely different route I should be thinking about to accomplish what I need.

My original program revolved around opening an Excel File, searching the various spreadsheets and returning data that fit the user's chosen criteria, how should I go about this with a web app written in ASP.NET and Visual Basic.

Thank you for any assistance anyone can provide.

Comment: You may run into problems with concurrent users - to start with you may need excel on the server (depending on what you are doing) and it's not going to scale very well.

Comment: @Paddy +1, also using Office COM automation from ASP.NET is not supported by Microsoft. Files should be modified using a library like Aspose's instead, but you'll still run into concurrency issues.

Comment: Your web-application should use a database server like SQL Server for its data storage. Maybe allow the user to upload an Excel workbook and your website will move the actual data into the database, that would be better.

Comment: Whatever you do, do not install Excel on the server or use Office Interop libraries in ASP.NET. Use dedicated managed libraries like EPPlus, NPOI, or Aspose.